# If-statement inside addClass function returns wrong value

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/tKL8E/31/). In this fiddle, there are two drop down menus. First is "Categorieën", second one is "Contact". The class that is assigned to a list item, determines whether the arrow on hover points left or right (whichever space has the most space left). The following code should take care of that. As you can see in the fiddle, however, the list item of the Contact drop down point the wrong way, it should point left.

```
$("ul.sub-menu > li:not(':last-child')").addClass(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
    offL = $this.offset().left,
    wW = $(window).width();

  if (offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width())) {
    return "over-left";
  } else {
    return "over-right";
  }
});
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
// We need to briefly show the sub-menu to get its offset and width
$("ul.sub-menu").css({
  visibility: "hidden",
  display: 'block'});

  $("ul.sub-menu > li:not(':last-child')").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass(function () {
      var offL = $this.offset().left,
        wW = $(window).width();
      if (offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width())) {
        return "over-left";
      } else {
        return "over-right";
      }
    });
  });

$("ul.sub-menu").css({
  visibility: "visible",
  display: "none"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the menu lines are not displayed, `$this.width()` is always equal to `0` and your condition is never met.

I have added `show()` before the class attribution loop to retrieve the right menu width value used in your function.

http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/33/

```
// RELEVANT CDOE
$("ul.sub-menu > li:not(':last-child')").show().addClass(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
    offL = $this.offset().left,
    wW = $(window).width();
  console.log(offL + ' ' + (wW/2) + ' ' + $this.width())

  if (offL >= ((wW / 2) - $this.width() - 238.5)) {
    return "over-left";
  } else {
    return "over-right";
  }
});
// /END RELEVANT CODE
```

Comment: Console logs the exact same values when `show` isn't there, so I don't think this solves it.